# Is a 6-1/2" or 7-1/4" circular saw better when I already have a 10" miter saw?

Tags: product-recommendation, circular-saw, miter

I'm new to home DIY projects. Someone gifted me a Homecraft H26-260L 10" miter saw ([product details on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LHUWAFA), [manual](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/67/6787987d-60c6-4f0b-848c-64e0071ff6bf.pdf)) a few years ago which I barely used. Now I want to buy a circular saw just to cut some wood here and there in the yard. Sometimes, it's just a thick tree branch that manual gardening tools aren't enough for. I heard 7-1/4" circular saws are the most common size but I found some good deal on a 6-1/2" one. Should I stick to the most common size or should I take the deal? Will what's missing from the 6-1/2" one as compared with the 7-1/4" one be compensated by the miter saw?

Comment: Does the 10" still work? If the question is whether 6 1/2 or 7 1/4 is better, I don't understand why the 10" was mentioned.

Comment: The type of cuts/wood should be consider.  Circular saws are good for some cuts, but other types of saws will do a better job.  A 7 1/4 will only make a bit over a three inch cut.

Comment: I would be _**exceedingly** cautious_ about using a circular saw of any size for cutting down tree limbs! It would be very easy for the branch to move and grab the saw blade, causing kickback that could yank the saw out of your hands, knock you off a ladder or just generally make for a Bad Day™.

Comment: If you are going after tree limbs with a power saw that's not a chainsaw, use a reciprocating saw (*e.g.* Sawzall®) and you stand a much better chance of ending the day with as many body parts as you started it with.

Comment: Do NOT use a circular saw for cutting down limbs, you will cut your OWN limb off!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been doing home maintenance and construction for over 1/2 century.

I would consider the 7 1/4 saw an essential for anyone that is serious about doing anything that requires wood to be cut. The 6 1/2 is smaller, lighter, but not as powerful and struggle to make all the cuts through the tough stuff like PT 2bys and 3/4 plywood.  I consider the 6 1/2 saw a tool box extra. (Make it something for loved ones to gift you when they don't know what to get.)

Go with the 7 1/4 for sure.
My father would say, "Better to have it and not need it, than need it and not have it."

Answer (score 4):

Circular saws and miter saws are different tools, for different tasks. A handheld circular saw is primarily used for breaking lumber down to rough sizes, when precision in either length or angle isn't needed. Framing for construction is the most common example. Getting rough cuts that are easier to handle than the 8' board and will be refined later is another.

By contrast, a miter saw is intended to make the kind of precise, repeatable cuts at specific angles that you would in the past have used a serious miter box and fine handsaw for, or maybe a table saw sled. It's a relatively recent tool, and framing carpenters will use it too.

A 7.25" saw, as others have said, can make some angled cuts that a 6" can't, and will generally have better motor and battery (assuming battery) so it cuts faster and longer. On the other hand, it will weigh considerably more. Tools for tasks, but for many tasks I've been content with my especially heavy plug-in handsaw with worm drive -- weighs like a beast but cuts like one.

It *is* possible to make precise, clean cuts with a handheld circular saw, with the right jigs/guides/blade. "Track saws" are the commercialized version of that... and arguably so is a miter saw, or even a table saw. But the bigger and more complicated and more precise the jig, the more you have to carry wood to it rather than it to the wood... and the more you may want to do rough cuts first to make that easier.

I agree with others that a circ saw is absolutely the wrong tool for use on any wood other than lumber. Appropriate handsaws work great on moderate sized tree limbs and are least damaging to a living tree, as well as being safest to use. Pros may use chain saws of various sizes, but I won't go near even a small chainsaw without proper safety equipment and training. If you really want a power saw for this task, there are limbing blades available for reciprocating saws, which strike me as a good balance between power and safety and control.

If you're going to work on living trees with any kind of saw, learn how to do a "triple cut" to minimize the risk of stripping bark.

Answer (score 3):

It may or may not matter for common cuts. Both sized saws can do 90 degree cuts on most common lumber. The big difference with a 7 1/4 saw is that it can do more common angled cuts. If you are fine hauling every board back to the miter saw to cut it at an angle, go for the smaller saw as it will be lighter and easier to carry. If you want the flexibility of being able to make those cuts anywhere, get the bigger saw.